# Unable to send Crypto JS encrypted data via ajax call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt a password and store it on Mongo LAB via Ajax call post.
I am getting the following error : 
I searched for the error but not getting what it means that it is pointing circularly.
Error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at n.$scope.signup (file:///C:/Users/naval.joshi/Desktop/eWallet/Assignment/Assignment/register.js:26:32)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:212:409), <anonymous>:4:209)
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:253:485)
    at n.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:133:221)
    at n.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:133:451)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:254:36)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Hf.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:35:217)
```

Code:

```
var reg = angular.module('register', ['ngRoute']);
reg.controller('regCntrl', function($scope,$http) {
     $scope.signup = function() {

        $scope.encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.password, "123"); 
        alert($scope.encryptedData);

        //alert("naval");

                      var inventory = {
                        name: $scope.name ,
                        email: $scope.email,
                        password: $scope.encryptedData,
                        phoneno:$scope.phoneno
                          };
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify( inventory ),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                console.log(msg);
            });
 };
    // populate the code to fill mongo DB
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix I believe ( similar to [How to pass encrypted data via browser (HTML5) session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874335/how-to-pass-encrypted-data-via-browser-html5-session-variable?noredirect=1#comment61315667_36874335)) is to add `.toString()` to your encrypted object. So change your encryption line to this:

```
$scope.encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.password, "123").toString();
```

Also just a tip, rather than `alert`ing values, `console.log` will show you what the actual value is of the variable you're dealing with)