# How to pass encrypted data via browser (HTML5) session variable

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, session-variables, cryptojs

I am trying to pass encrypted data via a **browser/client session variable** - not to be confused with **server-side session variable**:

encrypt:

```
var encrypted_user_id = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user_id, cipher_pass);
var encrypted_user_password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, cipher_pass);

sessionStorage.setItem('user_id', encrypted_user_id);
sessionStorage.setItem('user_password', encrypted_user_password);
```

decrypt:

```
var encrypted_user_id = sessionStorage.getItem('user_id');
var encrypted_user_password = sessionStorage.getItem('user_password');

var plaintext_user_id = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_user_id, cipher_pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
var plaintext_user_password = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_user_password, cipher_pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

**There is no error, but the plaintext is empty string.**

If I perform the exact same encryption/decryption using `variables` instead of `sessionStorage` it works fine.

What am I not understanding?  Is there something about session variables that is different than a local variable?

Comment: Just a quick comment, but you're doing `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_user_id, ...` to get the decrypted password - looks like you're decrypting the wrong variable.

Comment: @winhowes - Not sure what you mean?  `encrypted_user_id ` is passed into session variable and retrieved.  `user_id` is the original value that is encrypted to `encrypted_user_id` using `cipher_key` and decrypted using same key.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that you're getting a value for `encrypted_user_id` when you're getting it from session? And is it the same value you're putting into storage? Just trying to narrow down the issue

Comment: re my first comment: Your final line `encrypted_user_id` should be `encrypted_user_password` I believe

Comment: @winhowes - Yes, I have confirmed all variable at all phses in console.

Comment: @winhowes - Roger that, I have fixed my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/zkx4mh78/3/) to test it out. And I think the problem (although in fairness your original code seemed to work for me too) is that for the encryption you should do this instead:

```
var encrypted_user_id = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user_id, cipher_pass).toString();
```

Why? Without the to string, you're storing an object that JSON can't serialize, so when you're getting your object back from session storage you're getting back something different than you intended.

Comment: Normally, if one coerces the `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(...)` result to be converted to string like `"" + CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(...)` this should result in correct serialization, trying JSON serialization immediately breaks this.

Comment: Above fiddle is not working, I have updated the CDN and its working now in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/zkx4mh78/2/)